# Mediapipe Javascript Finger Detect Problem

Tags: mediapipe

I'm using mediapipe, I can detect right and left hand. But I also want to detect fingers eg. thumb and index finger. How can I do that?

```
  if (results.multiHandLandmarks && results.multiHandedness) {
    for (let index = 0; index < results.multiHandLandmarks.length; index++) {
      const classification = results.multiHandedness[index];
      const isRightHand = classification.label === 'Right';
      const landmarks = results.multiHandLandmarks[index];
      drawConnectors(
          canvasCtx3, landmarks, HAND_CONNECTIONS,
          {color: isRightHand ? '#00FF00' : '#FF0000'}),
      drawLandmarks(canvasCtx3, landmarks, {
        color: isRightHand ? '#00FF00' : '#FF0000',
        fillColor: isRightHand ? '#FF0000' : '#00FF00',
        radius: (x) => {
          return lerp(x.from.z, -0.15, .1, 10, 1);
        }       
      });

      if(isRightHand == true){
        canvasCtx3.fillText("Sağ el hareket ettirildi.",400,70);
      }
      else{
        canvasCtx3.fillText("Sol el hareket ettirildi.",10,70);
      }

    }
  }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Actually I tried to solve like below but i am not sure it will be good or not.
```
      var finger="empty";

      if(landmarks[4].y > landmarks[3].y){
        finger = "thumb";
        console.log(finger);
      }```